# include proxy username and password for WCF client in .NET core 3.1?

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-core, soap

I have a .net core 3.1 client app that call SOAP service located in the internet. I need some help to get out of the corporate proxy, below are the code so far.

```
var _InfoRequest = new ClientService.InfoRequest()
    {
        var1 = "",
        var2 = ""
    };

var binding = _client.Endpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;
binding.ProxyAddress = new Uri("http://proxy-ip-address:8585");
binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;

var _response =await _client.getCustomerInfoAsync(_InfoRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

How to use my Active Directory account ( **Username** & **Password** ) in the above code to access outside service through **Corporate Proxy Server**.

**Updated**

I have an exception as below :

```
Connection ID "16357073852515221623", Request ID "8000007a-0001-e300-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Exception: 
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://XYZ/services/MyService1 that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.EstablishProxyTunnel(HttpRequestHeaders headers, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.SendRequestAsync(Message message, TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at MyService1SoapCall.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.GetAsync() in D:\temp\MyService1\MyService1SoapCall\Controllers\WeatherForecastController.cs:line 92
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.UsePathBaseMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

And by the way, the corporate proxy server is accessible from the web server that hosted my service, to prove it , I added the Proxy setting same as I used in my C# code to the **IE browser**, its works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserName, Password and domain can be passed that way :

```
  _InfoRequest .ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "x";
  _InfoRequest .ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "pwd";
  _InfoRequest .ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "Domain";
```

Comment: I just updated the question with the exception that I faced after added 3 lines. Thanks.

Comment: After checking the code again, I replaced the proxy Server name with actual IP Address. and its works fine now. But there is something weird here, I tried to change the username and password with  wrong information, its still working.

Comment: Faris, I answered your question, your update deserve another question on its own